# Is there an easy way to remember Maxwell relation in thermodynamics?

Tags: thermodynamics, education

Maxwell relations are very important in thermodynamics, is there a way to easily remember it once and for all?

[image: Maxwell Relation]

Comment: In principle you just have to remember the expression for $\mathrm dU$ in the form given in your table. Everything else follows from Legendre transformations and the commutation of the partial derivatives. So if you understand how these relations arise you don't have to learn them by heart.

Comment: @JasonFunderberker that is true, but we still memorize equations/formulas for convenience no?

Comment: @JasonFunderberker For example, when we use Euler-Lagrange equation, we don’t want to derive it all the way from the least action principle. We memorize the EL equation and then directly apply it. This is also an act of least action principle per se.

Comment: I get your point, but at least in my opinion it is much more reasonable to remember $\mathrm dU$ (which one needs anyway in different situations) and then e.g. $A=U-TS$ instead of constructing some specific rules where e.g. one has to take care about some minus signs etc. In other words: The 'cost' of learning the constructed rule to obtain the Maxwell relations is, in my opinion, at least as high (if not higher) than the aforementioned procedure and then extracting the relations (again, the relations for $A,G,H$ are needed anyway). But again, this is a personal preference.

Comment: I had those on a test once. Just practice how to derive, then less to memorize, that's what we do in physics.

Comment: Simply put, no. As has been expanded on many times, the best course is to memorize the fundamental relation for $U$ (which even then comes intuitively from the Clausius entropy and reversible work), and then just apply derivatives as needed to get the Maxwell relations.

Answer (score 5):

I would never recommend anyone memorize the Maxwell relations, as anyone who needs  them should already be intimately familiar with the information needed to derive any one of them in twenty seconds (maybe sixty seconds the first few times):

1. The [fundamental relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_thermodynamic_relation) is $dU=T\,dS-P\,dV$. That is, there's two ways to add internal energy to a closed system (namely, heating it and doing work on it); $S$ and $V$ are the extensive variables that shift, driven by gradients in the intensive variables $T$ and $P$; and the unusual minus sign arises because pressure tends to *decrease* volume.
2. Other useful potentials are the enthalpy $H\equiv U+PV$ ($U$ plus the $P$–$V$ work needed to move the atmosphere out of the way of the system), the Helmholtz energy $F\equiv U-TS$ ($U$ minus the $T$–$S$ heating available to bring the system up to temperature), and the combination of these for constant surrounding pressure and temperature, the Gibbs free energy $G\equiv U+PV-TS$.
3. The corresponding differential forms of course switch variables and signs in the corresponding terms: $dH=T\,dS+V\,dP$, $dF=-S\,dT-P\,dV$, $dG=-S\,dT+V\,dP$.
4. **When we see a target for a Maxwell relation** (e.g., $\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial P}\right)_T$), **we immediately remember that whatever is on top** (here, $S$) **arose from differentiating a potential earlier** (here, $S=-\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial T}\right)_V=-\left(\frac{\partial G}{\partial T}\right)_P$). **Now that coefficient is being differentiated again, with respect to something else.** (If this isn't the case, then no Maxwell relation is applicable; an example is the constant-pressure heat capacity $C_P\equiv-T\left(\frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial T^2}\right)_P$.) **The Maxwell relations arise from noticing that $$\frac{\partial^2\Phi}{\partial X\partial Y}=\frac{\partial^2\Phi}{\partial Y\partial X}.$$
   for a potential $\Phi$ and state variables $X$ and $Y$.**
5. **Thus, we immediately write down the relevant thermodynamic relation**—here, $S$ being the coefficient and something else being differentiated with respect to $P$:
   $$dG=-S\,dT+V\,dP$$
   which we recall really means the expansion
   $$dG=\left(\frac{\partial G}{\partial T}\right)_PdT+\left(\frac{\partial G}{\partial P}\right)_TdP,$$
   so that
   $$\left(\frac{\partial (-S)}{\partial P}\right)_T=\frac{\partial G}{\partial T\partial P}=\frac{\partial G}{\partial P\partial T}=\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_P;$$
   $$\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial P}\right)_T=-\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_P$$
   **We confirm that the sign switches when only one minus sign appears in the thermodynamic relation.**

Note the complete lack of mnemonics or tricks or any information outside what the Maxwell relation implementer must already know as a thermodynamics framework. The key parts of the technique are shown in **bold**.

Notably, this strategy is easily extendable to an infinite number of other Maxwell relations that one wouldn't wish to take the time to memorize;  $\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial A}\right)_{V,T}=-\left(\frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial T}\right)_{V,A}$ for surface tension $\sigma$ and surface area $A$, for example, or $\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial N}\right)_{T,P}=\left(\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial P}\right)_{T,N}$ for chemical potential $\mu$ and particle number $N$. One simply writes these down after a few seconds of thought. Mnemonics can’t accommodate this extension.

Comment: To be honest I don't think this answer is helpful to the question asked. Sure Maxwell relation is easy to derive but there are cases when you need them right away, especially when you are a student dealing with thermodynamics homework problems. I don't think its a bad idea to memorize the equation after you are very familiar with the derivation. You wonldn't lose any insights and you save time.

Comment: I fully agree here, as I tried to point out in my comments under the question. One anyway needs the equations for $\mathrm dU$, $\mathrm dF$ always, so has to remember them. The Maxwell relations are then a trivial consequence. Of course, you can always learn everything by heart. But I cannot and I even think it is not necessary. Yet, there are cases where one does not want to derive the result over and over again (e.g. ELE, mentioned by OP). But here the derivation is extremely straightforward and can be done in a few moments; additionally, here we have to consider more special cases.

Comment: @IanHsiao "*but there are cases when you need them right away, especially when you are a student dealing with thermodynamics homework problems*" My point is that from what that student already knows (or should know), plus the bolded steps above, they *have* the Maxwell relations right away. They can simply write them down (though I like to jot down the relevant thermodynamic relation as well to make double-checking easier). But in any case, I've added a separate answer that addresses your point.

Answer (score 5):

You noted that you found my derivation-style answer unhelpful—which is fine—so here's a mnemonic technique for obtaining Maxwell relations: the thermodynamic square, as discussed, for instance, by Callen in his Section 7.2:

[image]

and by [Brannon in her comprehensive collection of recursion tables](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/280091244_Thermostatic_derivative_recursion_table_expressing_derivatives_in_terms_of_material_properties):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

All you need to remember is **PTVS**. Let me explain:

Basically I noticed if you write down the maxwell relation's in letters you get the following:

$$PTV=SVT, \ \ TVS=-PSV, \ \ VSP=TPS, \ \ -SPT=VTP$$

Where the letters are like this:
$$ PTV \rightarrow \left( \frac{\partial P}{\partial T} \right)_V$$

As you can see it is mirrored:

$$PTV=SVT, \ \ TVS=-PSV,$$

$$ SVT \rightarrow TVS $$

Even though it is not really needed I found the best mnemonic (in my opinion) to remember the Maxwell relations:

PTVS

That is all you need to remember.

Now to use it you have to take the first 3 letters and then change it into a partial derivative as such:

$$ PTV \rightarrow \left( \frac{\partial P}{\partial T} \right)_V$$

And then you take the next combination of the 3 letters and flip it and iterate through the PTVS- mnemnonic:

$$ TVS \rightarrow SVT \rightarrow \left( \frac{\partial S}{\partial V} \right)_T$$

First maxwell relations:

$$ \left( \frac{\partial P}{\partial T} \right)_V=\left( \frac{\partial S}{\partial V} \right)_T$$

Now we go one letter to the right and do the same:

P**TVS**

$$ TVS \rightarrow \left( \frac{\partial T}{\partial V} \right)_S $$

**P**T**VS**

$$ VSP \rightarrow PSV \rightarrow -\left( \frac{\partial P}{\partial S} \right)_V $$

We get a minus because we cycled through the whole acronym.

$$\left( \frac{\partial T}{\partial V} \right)_S= -\left( \frac{\partial P}{\partial S} \right)_V$$

And like this on.

Answer (score -1):

There are four variables $(T,V,P,S)$ here. Let's abstract them to $(A,B,C,D)$ for now.

Notice that for
$$\left(\frac{\partial A}{\partial B}\right)_C \tag{1}$$
the corresponding Maxwell relation is
$$\left(\frac{\partial D}{\partial C}\right)_B$$

The pattern here is that the two elements on the "denominator" *switch places*, and the "numerator" switches (or circulated) to the element being "left out" in the original expression eqn. (1), in this case, it is $D$.

In terms of $(T,V,P,S)$, if $S$ and $P$ are both in the "fraction", a negative sign is appended to the front. To memorize this, keep checking for **SuPer**.

Verify this with the Maxwell relation.

Comment: Consider to use \left( and \right) instead of just ( ) in math mode. Usually this looks much better: $\displaystyle (\frac{\partial A}{\partial B})_C$ vs $\displaystyle \left(\frac{\partial A}{\partial B}\right)_C$.

Comment: @JasonFunderberker Thanks for the suggestion! I'll have my post edited

Answer (score -1):

There is! I call it “upside down and inside out.” You can even hum along to [an OK Go song of that same name](https://youtu.be/LWGJA9i18Co) these days, which is nicer than what I had at college!

So the key is that you have to be able to determine from memory whether this manipulation is even likely to help. And *then* you can always derive it and look up any other details—“oh YEAH it was about commuting partial derivatives.” But the need for a mnemonic here, is just to have that initial spark where something looks familiar.

Let me explain the “inside out” thing first, this has to do with intensive and extensive thermodynamic variables that are conjugates of each other:

- Temperature (intensive) and entropy (extensive)
- Pressure and volume
- Chemical potential and amount

A Maxwell relation will always take two of these and turn them both inside out. A derivative of pressure with respect to temperature: this can also relate volume (pressure’s conjugate) to entropy (temperature's conjugate).

The upside down thing is that the symbols on the derivative flip sides from numerator to denominator, and you can kind of see that it *has to* flip if you take an intensive and an extensive variable in the derivative... You are going to have to have, say, both numerators intensive and both denominators extensive if you want the same behavior if I add “more of the same,” to a system (that is, grow the extensive quantities without changing the intensive quantities)... I guess that's based on treating a derivative as a ratio of deltas which isn't quite so easy with partial derivatives. But still, that's how it works in practice.

Once you know that Maxwell Relations are about turning things upside down and inside out, you can immediately look at a problem, “how is the pressure changing with the amount of heat that we put into it?”, recognize a partial, $\partial P/\partial S$ in this case, and do the inside out and upside down transform in your head to say “that is related to the temperature changes when you change the volume.” How exactly? That requires the full derivation, it turns out that they are negatives of each other. But at least you know that they are related—and you can immediately ask questions like “will they Maxwell relation help here? No...” to save yourself time and effort.